# Given a div with text-overflow: ellipsis; on focus, how can you remove the text-overflow?

Tags: css

I tried:

```
.listItem {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.listItem:focus {
    color: red;
    text-overflow: none !important;
}
```

But that has no effect on text-overflow though it does turn the color red. Ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no `none` value for `text-overflow` property. Default value is `clip`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/text-overflow

Comment: In mobile app only with this solution doesn't work. Needs `white-space: normal`

Answer (score 4):

You can set the `text-overflow` to `clip` or you can set the `white-space` to `normal` or `overflow` to `visible`. The second two options are necessary conditions for the ellipsis to work, so changing them will turn it off.

Comment: This should be the answer.